# Trigger a fade out animation when slider's value changes

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to bind the **Opacity** property of a Rectangle shape to the Slider's value. So that when its value passes 2, the Rectangle **fades out** and when we decrease the slider's value and it passes the value of 2 it appears again with a **fade in animation**. What's the best practice to do this?

```
<Window x:Class="Layout.AnimateOpacity"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="AnimateOpacity" Height="300" Width="300">
    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               Height="300" Width="300">
        <Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                Width="300" Height="200"
                Background="Black">
            <Rectangle x:Name="myRectangle" 
                       Width="100" Height="100"
                       Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="60"
                       Fill="Yellow">
            </Rectangle>
        </Canvas>
        <Slider x:Name="mySlider" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" 
                Height="30" Width="250" 
                Value="1" Maximum="3" Minimum="0" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook `ValueChanged` event of slider and there you can do animation based on new and old value of slider.

**XAML:**

```
<Slider x:Name="mySlider" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" 
        Height="30" Width="250" 
        Value="1" Maximum="3" Minimum="0"
        ValueChanged="mySlider_ValueChanged" />
```

**Code behind:**

```
private void mySlider_ValueChanged(object sender,
                                   RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
   if (e.NewValue > 2 && e.OldValue <= 2)
   {
      DoubleAnimation fadeOutAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0.0,
                                     new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
      myRectangle.BeginAnimation(Rectangle.OpacityProperty, fadeOutAnimation);
   }
   else if(e.NewValue < 2 && e.OldValue >= 2)
   {
      DoubleAnimation fadeInAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1.0,
                                     new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
      myRectangle.BeginAnimation(Rectangle.OpacityProperty, fadeInAnimation);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The code you provided worked pretty well, can it be done using triggers in xaml?

Comment: Yeah it can be that will be more complex though. You have to create `converter` which will return True, false based on two if conditions and based on those two values you can have `Trigger on DockPanel` to toggle opacity using `StoryBoard`.

Comment: Yeah I was afraid I had to use conveters :( I was hoping may be there was an easy way :p, the code behind will do the job though.